# How can I adjust the external header/footer margin in memoir class?

Tags: margins, memoir, page-numbering

I am working in a memoir class document, with a template I found on the internet and customised a bit.

I would like to change the number's and header's place, putting it further from the edges of the sheet, but I can't figure out how (see the picture) [image: I want to rise the distance of the red arrows] 
Would someone have an idea ?

Here is the changes I use for the page layout:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{*}{0.8}
\setulmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{45pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\usepackage[margin=0.7cm]{caption}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

I also would like to have this numbering style in all over my document (and not sometimes on top or in the centre).

Thanks a lot !

PS: I am new in stackexchange, so sorry if I asked it wrong.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think you need declare the `\settrimmedsize` and `\settypeblocksize`

Comment: These commands by themselves will not produce the effect you've posted. Please provide an MWE as requested.

Comment: By creating a MWE, I found that the template I used was using
\pagestyle{ruled}
and it seems that this is the problem.
Thanks for all !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was resolved by making an MWE and finding the malicious line of code that produced the unwanted output.